# Dynamic or Fixed height for Modal window

Tags: modal-windows

Need your help to clarify one query related to the modal. My question is whether the modal height should be dynamic or fixed? Dynamic I refer to is that the modal height varies based on the amount of content & fixed modal will always have a fixed height regardless of the amount of content. For fixed modal, there will be an internal scrollbar to scroll the content. Sample images attached (first image represent the dynamic & the other 2 fixed).
Which approach is the correct one as per the UX principles & widely used one?
Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran a usability test in the past for a similar design and I can confidently recommend the fixed height and a scroll bar once the number of items overflows the height of the modal. So number 2.